# Sending JSON/GSON request within Java Servlets results in "Bad request"

Tags: java, json, servlets, request

I have the code of the servlet where I want to get a valid response. This is the original layout of the request

```
 {
  "function": "Check",
  "teamId": "<teamId>",
  "teamKey": "<teamKey>",
  "requestId": "<request-id>",
  "firstName": "<FirstName>",
  "lastName": "<LastName>",
  "ticketNumber": "<ticket-num>"
}
```

I have this within my servlet in Intellij.

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.*;
import org.apache.*;
import org.apache.http.*;



@WebServlet(name = "Logincheck", urlPatterns = {"/Logincheck"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {


String teamID = "IC106-2";
String teamKey = "1b3741ccf6d9ec5245055370125d901e";
String url="http://fys.securidoc.nl:11111/Ticket";
int Min = 1;
int Max = 100;
int REQ_ID =  Min + (int)(Math.random() *((Max - Min)+1));

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

//index.html form user input
     String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lname");
    String ticketNummer = request.getParameter("ticketnr");

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    URL object=new URL(url);

    String ticketCheck = "{\"function:\"Check\",\"teamId\":\"IC106-2\",\"teamKey\":\"1b3741ccf6d9ec5245055370125d901e\",\"requestId\":\""+REQ_ID+"\",\"firstName\":\""+fname+"\",\"lastName\":\""+lastName+"\",\"ticketNumber\":\""+ticketNummer+"\"}";



    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(ticketCheck);
    writer.flush();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String jsonResponseString = sb.toString();
    JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(jsonResponseString);

    int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
    if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("" + sb.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
    }





}
```

Now when I hit run it opens my index.html and when I click the login button to /Logincheck it responses(within intellij):

```
Bad Request
```

The Teamkey and TeamID are 100% correct, but I'm probably overlooking something that has to do with Json. I have minimal experience with Json and servlets in general. Like do I make hardcoded login and ticket credentials, or is the input of the user correct already correct? I should expect this response:

```
{
  "ticketStatus": "<ticket-status>",
  "requestId": "<request-id>",
  "result": "<result-code>",
  "resultText": "<result-text>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your json data to request body. For this you can use `OutputStreamWriter` class to write to the output stream of `HttpURLConnection` like below:

```
String ticketCheck = "{ \"function\":\"Check\",\"teamId\":IC106-2,\"teamKey\":1b3741ccf6d9ec5245055370125d901e,\"requestId\":1,\"firstName\":\"" + fname + "\" ,\"lastName\":\""+lastName+"\",\"ticketNumber\":\"\"" + ticketnummer + "\"}";

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
writer.write(ticketCheck);
//this line closes the outputstream and actually makes the http request is sent
writer.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It changed the response to another error(Bad Request). Which means your tip actually made impact on the response, however I have no clue how to solve this problem. I'll search in the meanwhile, but if you're familiar with this error could you please explain how I should be able to solve it?

Comment: Yes, I saw your reply late sorry, http status 400 (bad request) means exactly as you said, in this request when you set the header Content-Type as json you must provide a correct json structure for the http body. I am glad you figure out and you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Simple quote typo. "bad request" means bad syntax and I forgot to add \" next to function.

```
    String ticketCheck = "{\"function\":\"Check\",\"teamId\":\"IC106-2\",\"teamKey\":\"1b3741ccf6d9ec5245055370125d901e\",\"requestId\":\""+REQ_ID+"\",\"firstName\":\""+fname+"\",\"lastName\":\""+lastName+"\",\"ticketNumber\":\""+ticketNummer+"\"}";
```

correct json above